# extract only the subfolder, not the whole folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, tar, python-zipfile

Is it possible to extract only a `subfolder` from an archive, rather than the whole folder?

I.E. : I have my `.zip`/`.tar.gz` file named `my_archive`, which has inside folder `folder_1`. `folder_1` has inside `subfolder_1`, `subfolder_2` and `subfolder_3`. I only want to directly extract `subfolder_1` and `subfolder_2`. How do I do it?

It is ok if I copy `folder_3` as well, the most important part is to go directly inside `folder_1`

Comment: do not you want subfolder_3?

Comment: If necessary, I can take `subfolder_3` as well, the most important part is to go directly to the subfolder.

Comment: See [`namelist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) and [`extractall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall).